# Multiple Polymorphic Attributes on one Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, polymorphic-associations

I've been creating an application which has several different model types which act as different page types. 
I currently have a Posts model with two polymorphic attributes: Postable and Posterable, where these are the pages on which posts are posted, and the authors of each post respectively.
For example, I want users to be able to author and receive a post, whilst I also want a Group to be able to receive a post and author one via an admin user.

My Post model is currently as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
before_create :set_latlong

belongs_to :posterable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true

default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
validates :posterable_id, presence: true
validates :posterable_type, presence: true

def set_latlong
    self.latitude = posterable.latitude
    self.longitude = posterable.longitude
end

def self.from_users_favourited_by(user)
    favourited_user_ids = "SELECT favourite_id FROM favouriteusers
                                WHERE favourited_id = :user_id"
    where("posterable_id IN (#{favourited_user_ids}) OR posterable_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id)
end
```

end

Post scheme is:

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
t.string   "content"
t.integer  "posterable_id"
t.string   "posterable_type"
t.float    "latitude"
t.float    "longitude"
t.integer  "postable_id"
t.string   "postable_type"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

end

I believe these are all workable too allow for various models to post on various model pages.  However, I'm not quite sure how to implement this quite yet, the Post controller is as follows:

```
class PostssController < ApplicationController
```

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :load_posterable

def new
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
  end

def create
    @posterable = load_posterable
    @post = @posterable.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.postable = find_postable
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Post created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.present?
      @post.destroy
    end
    redirect_to root_url
  end

private

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end

def load_posterable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  resource_name = resource.singularize.classify
  if resource_name = "user"
    @posterable = current_user
  else 
    @posterable = resource_name.constantize.find(id)
  end
end

def find_postable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  resource_name = resource.singularize.classify
end
```

end

I believe the key to making this work is separating the "resource" in the load_posterable and find_postable methods, which I got from the Railscast tutorial on polymorphic association, but I don't really know how I would differentiate between these within the same model?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. So wrong I don't event know where to start. Why are comment authors polymorphic? Admin is a subtype of user. You are overcomplicating stuff, look for more simple common elements in models and abstract them better. For user/admin thing you may want to look into STI, however a simple attribute should be enough.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel admins are for the specific instances, not a user sub-class and an Admin attribute has been added (i.e. When a user creates a group they are automatically the admin of that group). What they can then do is post on a user or groups wall as either themselves or as any group that they are the admin of.

Comment: WTF is that? `resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]`. Read about Rails routing, never seen anyone doing anything like that and for a good reason.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I believe I got it from http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=comments, sorry I'm only new to rails and just finding my feet!

Comment: OMG, something like that in Rails casts?Can't believe my eyes. anyway. Ditch Railscasts and take a look at guides.rubyonrails.com. Also try something simpler first, like a single polymorphic association, in the end you will learn and understand more faster. When it comes to implementation I would still suggest taking my answer. This is decorator design pattern and it's a really good way to go.

Comment: I couldn't really work out how to implement your answer, so ended up just creating two separate models; post and status. This has made the job far easier. I would mark your answer as correct, but I didn't use it so probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need a Profile model, which user/admin will use to act on the site with.

You should create and select it automatically for users (default one), and then separate one for each group one becomes an admin of.

Profile in itself should not really hold any attributes, just delegate them over association (maybe a polymorphic one if you wish) to the user or other model.

This way you have quite a clean interface, Profile class will be kind-of decorator for your models.

On controller level you should have a `current_profile` method similar to `current_user` in Devise which will store/retrieve profile id from session.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: I've added my code, so hopefully this will give you a better idea of what I'm asking.